# return more than one row as comma separated values from case when statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to create a function in Postgresql with 4 arguments that returns a table(multiple rows). 
Arguments: `in_customer_id, in_start_date, in_end_date, in_risk_flag`

The sql query I am using in that function is:

```
select * from customer as k 
where k.customer_id IN (case when $1 = 0 then (select distinct(customer_id) from customer) 
                             when $1 != 0 then $1 
                             end) 
and k.start_date >= $2 
and k.end_date <= $3 
and k.risk_flag IN (case when $4 = 0 then (select distinct(risk_flag) from customer)
                         when $4 != 0 then $4 
                         end)
```

Error I am getting is error [21000]: `more than one row returned by subquery used as an expression`.

Is there any way to get return from case statement as (1,2,3,4,5,6) (comma separated values) instead of a column with multiple rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. Writing `distinct (customer_id)` makes no sense. And in a sub-select that's used for an `IN` condition the `distinct` is useless anyway.

---

It seems that you want to select a specific customer in case you pass a parameter, otherwise you want to select all of them. As far as I can tell, you don't need a sub-select for that. Something like that should do it:

```
where k.customer_id = case 
                         when $1 <> 0 then $1 
                         else k.customer_id
                      end
```

It essentially turns the condition to `where customer_id = customer_id` when the first parameter is passed as `0` (although you should better use a null value for that, rather then a "magic" value like zero)

This assumes that `customer_id` is defined as `NOT NULL` otherwise this will not work.

You can apply the same pattern for `risk_id` (again: it will only work if `risk_id` can not contain `NULL` values).

Answer (score 0):

This logic is usually simplified to avoid the `case` in the `where` clause:

```
where ($1 = 0 or $1 = k.customer_id) and
      . . .
```